# correct algo for deep copying a string in c++

Tags: c++, constructor, deep-copy

this is the code i have for deep copying a string in copy constructor
so is the logic correct??I think there may be memory leak and i am trying to fix that.m.pStatus is initialised

```
class Monkey
{
public:

// insert your code here
Monkey();
Monkey(const Monkey& m);
Monkey& operator=(const Monkey& m);
~Monkey();
// accessors
int getX();
int getY();
char *getStatus();
void deepCopy(const Monkey& m);
// global variables (incremented each creation or destruction)
static int numStringsCreated;
static int numStringsDestroyed;

private:
        // Do not change this data
    int x;
    int y;
    char *pStatus;

};
```

```cpp
void Monkey::deepCopy(const Monkey& m)
{
    
    if (m.pStatus)
    {
        // allocate memory for our copy
        pStatus= new char[sizeof(m.pStatus)];
 
        for (int i{ 0 }; i < sizeof(m.pStatus); ++i)
            pStatus[i] = m.pStatus[i];
    }
    else
        pStatus = nullptr;
}


    Monkey::Monkey(const Monkey& m)
    {
        deepCopy(m);
        numStringsCreated++;
    }
```

Comment: `sizeof(m.pStatus)` is very likely wrong, but without seeing the definition all we can do is guess. You probably want `strlen`. Consider a [mcve]. if `pStatus` points to previously allocated memory then this is also a memory leak.

Comment: If `pStatus` is a pointer sizeof(pStatus) is wrong. It returns the number of bytes for the pointer itself which is likely 4 for 32 bit code and 8 for 64. You probably wanted to use strlen()

Comment: Why are you not using `std::string` ?

Comment: `new char[]` is *not* a string, it's a character array. If you're going to code in `C++`, use the facilities given to you, not the legacy `C` stuff. Otherwise, you're that strange variety known as a `C+` developer :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo is that better, worse, or the same as a Three Star Programmer?

Comment: Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted.

Comment: Side note: Rather than a member function like `deepCopy`, prefer to use the copy constructor and assignment operator. The assignment operator can be written [laughably easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) once you have the copy constructor up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `sizeof(pStatus)`. Unless the variable is fixed sized array, it will evaluate to the size of a pointer, not the length of the string.

`strlen` and `strcpy` for classic C string length and copy operations.

This is closer to what you want.  It ensures that it cleans up any previous allocation and implicitly handles the case where a self assignment is made (e.g. `m.deepCopy(m)`) by allocating the copy first before deleting the old.   You could make an additional optimization to say `if (m.pStatus == pStatus)` and skip the copy operation entirely.

I'm working under the assumption that pStatus was initialized to null or something valid in the constructor.

```
void Monkey::deepCopy(const Monkey& m)
{
    char* psz = nullptr;
    if (m.pStatus)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(m.pStatus);
        psz = new char[len+1]; // +1 for null char
        strcpy(pStatus, m.pStatus);
    }

    delete [] pStatus;
    pStatus = psz;      
}
```

But if `pStatus` was a `std::string` you wouldn't need to do any of this allocation stuff and you likely wouldn't need to overload the assignment operator or copy constructor.

Comment: thanks for the help.It pointed me in the right direction.my code is correct except that strcpy is not not accepted by my compiler and so i used strncpy_s.Also it needed a delete statement like in your code.

Comment: Does your code correctly handle `m.deepCopy(m)` ?  That is, a self-copy. From what I see above, it does not handle that implicitly.

Comment: Also, if you simply had pStatus as a `std::string` type you would not need to have a copy constructor nor overloaded assignment operator. You might not even need  a destructor too.  The default implementations of these operations would to the right thing.

Comment: thanks i will make that addition